# How to insert and query clients favorite restaurants in supabase

Tags: postgresql, flutter, dart, supabase, supabase-database

I have created clients, restaurants and favorites tables in supabase and linked them using foreign keys, I want to list a client's favorite restaurant if any and also insert favorite restaurants when the client clicks on the favorite icon.

The created schema looks like this

```
clients
  client_id uuid(pk),
  name text,
  email text,
  avatar text,
  points float4,
  favorite_id uuid(fk),
```

```
restaurants
  restaurant_id uuid(pk),
  name text,
  description text,
  logo text,
  location text,
  menu json,
```

```
favorites
  favorite_id uuid(pk),
  created_at now(),
  client_id uuid(fk),
  restaurant_id uuid(fk),
```

For inserting a favorite restaurant to a client

```dart
final res = await supabase.client
            .from('favorites')
            .insert({
              'client_id': user.id,
              'restaurant_id': res.id
             })
             .execute();

///Which works fine
```

```dart
For querying a favorite restaurant of a client
final res = await supabase.client
            .from('restaurants')
            .select('*, favorites!inner(*)')
            .eq('client_id ', user.id);

///Doesn't work at all`
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work!

```dart
final res = await supabase.client
  .from('clients')
  .select('*, restaurants(*)')
  .eq('client_id ', user.id);
```